# Redirect user to another PHP page with parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to redirect user to another PHP page to edit a SQL table, when a button is clicked. This is the code:

```
 $("#modificaDipinto").click(function(){

    var tipo = <?php echo json_encode($tipo_opera); ?>; 
    var codice = <?php echo json_encode($cod); ?>;
    var titolo = <?php echo json_encode($titolo); ?>;
    var annoCreaz = <?php echo json_encode($annoCreaz); ?>;
    var museo = <?php echo json_encode($museo); ?>;
    var dimensioni = <?php echo json_encode($dim); ?>;
    var tipoPittura = <?php echo json_encode($tipo_pittura); ?>;
    window.location.href = "modifica.php?codice="+codice+"&tipo="+tipo+"&titolo="+titolo+"&annoCreaz="+annoCreaz+"&museo="+museo+"&dimensioni="+dimensioni+"&tipoPitt="+tipoPittura;

 }
 });
```

Those variables are PHP variables declared above. I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Comment: Please look into `encodeURIComponent()`, you're asking for trouble putting unescaped values into a URL.

Answer (score 2):

You have extra } closing curly brace.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#modificaDipinto").click(function(){

    var tipo = <?php echo json_encode($tipo_opera); ?>; 
    var codice = <?php echo json_encode($cod); ?>;
    var titolo = <?php echo json_encode($titolo); ?>;
    var annoCreaz = <?php echo json_encode($annoCreaz); ?>;
    var museo = <?php echo json_encode($museo); ?>;
    var dimensioni = <?php echo json_encode($dim); ?>;
    var tipoPittura = <?php echo json_encode($tipo_pittura); ?>;
    window.location.href = "modifica.php?codice="+codice+"&tipo="+tipo+"&titolo="+titolo+"&annoCreaz="+annoCreaz+"&museo="+museo+"&dimensioni="+dimensioni+"&tipoPitt="+tipoPittura;


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is an extra flower bracket. This should work actually

```
$("#modificaDipinto").click(function(){

var tipo = <?php echo json_encode($tipo_opera); ?>; 
var codice = <?php echo json_encode($cod); ?>;
var titolo = <?php echo json_encode($titolo); ?>;
var annoCreaz = <?php echo json_encode($annoCreaz); ?>;
var museo = <?php echo json_encode($museo); ?>;
var dimensioni = <?php echo json_encode($dim); ?>;
var tipoPittura = <?php echo json_encode($tipo_pittura); ?>;
window.location.href = "modifica.php?codice="+codice+"&tipo="+tipo+"&titolo="+titolo+"&annoCreaz="+annoCreaz+"&museo="+museo+"&dimensioni="+dimensioni+"&tipoPitt="+tipoPittura;});
```

If this does not work, you can use PHP SESSION variables in order to pass variables to one page to another

Comment: I get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Answer (score 0):

1 redundant curly bracket in your code, remove it:

```
$("#modificaDipinto").click(function(){
            var tipo = <?php echo json_encode($tipo_opera); ?>; 
            var codice = <?php echo json_encode($cod); ?>;
            var titolo = <?php echo json_encode($titolo); ?>;
            var annoCreaz = <?php echo json_encode($annoCreaz); ?>;
            var museo = <?php echo json_encode($museo); ?>;
            var dimensioni = <?php echo json_encode($dim); ?>;
            var tipoPittura = <?php echo json_encode($tipo_pittura); ?>;
            window.location.href = "modifica.php?codice="+codice+"&tipo="+tipo+"&titolo="+titolo+"&annoCreaz="+annoCreaz+"&museo="+museo+"&dimensioni="+dimensioni+"&tipoPitt="+tipoPittura;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `json_encode()` in `modifica.php` file instead of your jquery script. This way you are sending json data in url parameters which may be causing this error.